# Just check out a branch and untracked files exist

Tags: git

I just check out from a remote branch and I found that there're untracked files just after check out. How is this possible?

I tried to commit the untracked files and pushed. However there still are untracked files when I check out the branch again.

What's the correct way to fix this?

Comment: If you want a mirror of origin: `git reset --hard origin/yourbranch` - use `git clean` to remove untracked files.

Comment: most likely your ``.gitignore`` changed